# Shapeless HList implicit resolution - diverging implicit expansion

Tags: scala, shapeless, hlist

This is really bugging me. I am getting a `diverging implicit expansion for type Meta[Field2 :: HNil]` error which I try and compile the following:

```
case class Field() extends StaticAnnotation
case class Group() extends StaticAnnotation
case class Message() extends StaticAnnotation

@Field case class Field1(value: String)
@Field case class Field2(value: String)
@Field case class Field3(value: String)
@Group case class Group1(field1: Field1, field2: Field2)
@Message case class Message1(field3: Field3, group1: Group1)

trait Meta[T]

object Meta {
  implicit val hNil: Meta[HNil] = new Meta[HNil] {}
  implicit def field[TField](implicit a: Annotation[Field, TField]): Meta[TField] = new Meta[TField] {}
  implicit def hcons[Head, Tail <: HList](implicit h: Meta[Head], t: Meta[Tail]) : Meta[H :: T] = new Meta[H :: T] {}
  implicit def group[TGroup, ParamList <: HList](implicit a: Annotation[Group, TGroup], g: Generic.Aux[TGroup, ParamList], p: Meta[ParamList]): Meta[TGroup] = new Meta[TGroup] {}
  implicit def message[TMessage, ParamList <: HList](implicit a: Annotation[Message, TMessage], g: Generic.Aux[TMessage, ParamList], p: Meta[ParamList]): Meta[TMessage] = new Meta[TMessage] {}
}

object TestApp extends App {
  // throws compile exception here...
  implicitly[Meta[Message1]]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the process of expanding `Meta[Message1]`:

- When expanding `Meta[Message1]` with `message` the compiler needs `Meta[Field3 :: Group1 :: HNil]`
- Later, when expanding `Meta[Group1]` with `group` it needs `Meta[Field1 :: Field2 :: HNil]`

The compiler sees, that in this branch it has already expanded type constructor `::` of at least the same complexity (i.e., with the same number of elements in the `HList`). So it assumes, that this expansion branch results in an infinite loop, and reports implicit divergence.

To prevent this behaviour you can use `shapeless.Lazy`. From the documentation:

> Wraps a lazily computed value. Also circumvents cycles during implicit
>   search, or wrong implicit divergences as illustrated below, and holds
>   the corresponding implicit value lazily.

So to fix this problem you can wrap in `Lazy` the expansion of `Head` in `hcons`:

```
implicit def hcons[Head, Tail <: HList](implicit 
  h: Lazy[Meta[Head]], 
  t: Meta[Tail]
): Meta[Head :: Tail] = 
  new Meta[Head :: Tail] {}
```

Usually you should wrap in `Lazy` the expansions of heads in `HList` and `Coproduct` rules, and also the expansion of `Repr` in `Generic` rules. The latter is not necessary here, I think, because you'll necessary go through `hcons` rule, that already has `Lazy`, to get from one `Group` or `Message` to another).

Comment: I've learnt something new here - thank you! So in the general scenario where I will have groups within groups, if I've understood you correctly I'll also need a `Lazy` on the `t` param of the `hcons` method.

Comment: @Cheetah No, it's OK to leave `t` without `Lazy`, because the size of the tail is growing smaller with each recursion step, and the compiler is OK with following it to the end. You can get to a larger or same size hlist only through `h`. In general you may need `Lazy` in `p` of `group` and `message`, because it may be possible for `group` to recursively call `group` again. Here it's not required, because with this definition `group` can call `group` only through the   head of `hcons`, which already has `Lazy`.